# How to allow user to select a video in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In MonoTouch, I see a ton of examples on how to select a photo or take a photo using `UIImagePickerController`, however, I don't see anything on videos.

How can I prompt a user to select a video file only from their library (no photos)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign a string[] with the media types you want the image picker controller to read. The available media types are

1. public.image
2. public.movie

So for the image picker to read only video files:

```
UIImagePickerController myImgPick = new UIImagePickerController();
myImgPick.MediaTypes = new string[] { "public.movie" };
```

You can also check for the available media types, depending on the media source (camera, photo library etc.):

```
string[] mediaTypesForCamera = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera);
```

Comment: This does look correct, although myImgPick.MediaTypes = new string[] { "public.video" }; causes a NSInvalidArgumentException: 'No available types for Source 0' - any idea why that is?

Comment: Oh, I always get this wrong: the correct string is "public.movie" not "public.video". Edited my answer. It would be a good practice to always check the AvailableMediaTypes return value though.